# Audio file stream in HTTP Post Jersey using Java

Tags: java, jersey, http-post, filestream

I have been stuck on an issue for the last couple of days and frankly I am out of ideas. What I am trying to do is to host an rest service using Jersey that will accept a post request with stream of audio data in its payload.

Issue I have been running into is that that I loose data consistency (I am running CRC check on both client and server) and after 8 reads of with 1024 bytes buffer CRC between data sent and data received becomes inconsistent. It works just fine when I am dealing with text or content of smaller size. Code is attached, can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Server:

```
@POST
@Consumes("audio/wav")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String streamCommand(@Context HttpServletRequest request ) throws Exception 
{       
    CRC32 crc = new CRC32();
    InputStream stream = request.getInputStream();
    byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1024];
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    while (stream.read(readBuffer) > -1)
    {
        crc.update(readBuffer);
        builder.append(new String(readBuffer));
        System.out.println(crc.getValue());
    }

    return builder.toString();      
}
```

Client:

```
static final String SOUND_FILE_NAME = "SoundTest.wav";

@BeforeClass
public static void setup() throws Exception
{
    soundStream = classloader.getResourceAsStream(SOUND_FILE_NAME);
}

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {

    PipedOutputStream stream = new PipedOutputStream();

    DataStreamer data = new DataStreamer(stream, soundStream);
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/EVAFrontEnd/webapi/users/1/devices/1/command");        
    post.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "audio/wav");       

    InputStreamEntity requestEntity = new InputStreamEntity(new PipedInputStream((PipedOutputStream) stream), -1);
    post.setEntity(requestEntity);                

    executor.execute(data);
    executor.shutdown();

    HttpResponse r = client.execute(post);
    assertNotNull(r);

}
```

Data Streamer:

```
public class DataStreamer implements Runnable {

OutputStream writeStream;
CheckedInputStream readStream;
static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DataStreamer.class);

public DataStreamer(OutputStream stream, InputStream readingStrem) {
    this.writeStream = stream;
    this.readStream = new CheckedInputStream(readingStrem, new Adler32());
}

@Override
public void run() 
{
    CRC32 crc = new CRC32();
    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (readStream.read(buffer) > -1) {
            crc.update(buffer);
            System.out.println(crc.getValue());
            writeStream.write(buffer);
        }

        System.out.println("END CRC");
        readStream.close();
        writeStream.close();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Unable to stream data.", e);
    }
}
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to always save the number of bytes written by

```
bytes_read = readStream.read(buffer);
```

into a variable, because that method sometimes gives a short result. Then use ArrayList.copyOfRange to create a subarray [0 ... bytes_read-1] from the buffer with only the valid bytes.